# Compile libcmaes with mingw

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to make a windows .exe file with Ubuntu 20.04.1 (VM on Windows host).

The source code includes libcmaes, so I can compile the follwing code with `sudo x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -fopenmp -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/libcmaes -L/usr/lib -std=c++11 -o output.exe source.cpp -lcmaes` and the generated files worked fine on ubuntu.
But I couldn't compile it when `g++` is replaced `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` and terminal returned the error.

I commented out a little bit from the libcmaes sample code and found that it is probably not linked.
Here is the code and the error content.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmaes.h>
using namespace libcmaes;

FitFunc object = [](const double *x, const int N)
{
  double val = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    val += x[i];
  return val;
};

int main()
{
  int dim = 10; // problem dimensions.
  std::vector<double> x0(dim,20.0);
  double sigma = 0.1;
  CMAParameters <> cmaparams(x0,sigma);
  //cmaparams.set_algo(BIPOP_CMAES);
  //CMASolutions cmasols = cmaes<>(object,cmaparams);
  //std::cout << "best solution: " << cmasols << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "optimization took " << cmasols.elapsed_time() / 1000.0 << " seconds\n";
  //return cmasols.run_status();
  return 0;
}
```

Result

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc67KYiT.o:finish.cpp:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `libcmaes::CMAParameters<libcmaes::GenoPheno<libcmaes::NoBoundStrategy, libcmaes::NoScalingStrategy> >::CMAParameters(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, double const&, int const&, unsigned long long const&, libcmaes::GenoPheno<libcmaes::NoBoundStrategy, libcmaes::NoScalingStrategy> const&)'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cc67KYiT.o:finish.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `libcmaes::CMAParameters<libcmaes::GenoPheno<libcmaes::NoBoundStrategy, libcmaes::NoScalingStrategy> >::~CMAParameters()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please tell me what I should do.

Comment: I copied each files from /usr/lib/~ to /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/~ and changed the command `$ sudo x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -fopenmp -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/eigen3 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/libcmaes  -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -std=c++11 -o finish.exe finish.cpp -lcmaes` , but didn't compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're crosscompiling on Linux for Windows, so `-L/usr/lib` is wrong when using MinGW, as it points to the Ubuntu libraries, not the Windows libraries.

Instead you should make sure `-I` and `-L` point to your Windows build of libsmaes.

Comment: I took your advice and changed the command, but the result was the same. I copied some directry into /usr/x86_64-w64~/include and libcmaes.a into /usr/x86_64-w64-~/lib, should I rebuild libcmaes itself for windows? That would be a bit of a problem.

Comment: Yes, you need a Windows version of libcmaes, otherwise you won't have the library file. libcmaes compiles on Windows with MinGW-w64 and cmake.

Comment: Okay. I've been studying CMake with my head in my hands for a while now, so maybe I can do it. I will report back when it is done. Your words have given me the courage to take the plunge into CMake, thank you.

Comment: I created a .cmake file in which  MinGW-w64 is specified as the compiler and accomplished building libcmaes with MinGW-w64! I put the generated libcmaes.a into the lib directory(in this time, /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib), and the target code was compiled without any problems. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you create a cmake file? CMakeLists.txt is already available in libcmaes...

Comment: @BrechtSanders "libcmaes compiles on Windows with MinGW-w64 and cmake" I have been unable to sucessfully build it with MinGW on Windows, and the docs don't mention it being supported (I'm facing [this issue](https://github.com/CMA-ES/libcmaes/issues/211))

Comment: @joaocandre libcmaes 0.10 builds fine here. Which version did you try to build?

Comment: @BrechtSanders 0.10 as well. When build just the library, fails during linking (I suspect library paths aren't properly configured). If I use it as a dependency on another project (linking the target to my executable), I get the error I linked above.

Comment: static or shared build (both your project and the libcmaes dependency)?

Comment: shared build (libcmaes default), I link my project with `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libcmaes::cmaes)` iirc